# Update na mesma tabela

Tags: sql

**tenho esta tabela assim:**

```
CODIGO_AULA DATA_AULA  TURMA
----------- ---------- ----------
1           2018-01-19 MEC-001
2           2018-01-19 MEC-001
1           2018-01-20 MEC-001
2           2018-01-20 MEC-001
1           2018-01-21 MEC-001
2           2018-01-21 MEC-001
1           2018-01-22 MEC-001
2           2018-01-22 MEC-001
```

Preciso fazer um update na mesma de acordo com essa situação passada,passei por parâmetro a data : 2018-01-20

**Ficando assim**:

```
1           2018-01-21 MEC-001
2           2018-01-21 MEC-001
1           2018-01-22 MEC-001
2           2018-01-22 MEC-001
1           2018-01-23 MEC-001
2           2018-01-23 MEC-001
```

ele só vai mexer da data que passei até o fim da tabela.
O que preciso e pegar é fazer um update da data que passei e vim subindo ?

Comment: A sua dúvida não ficou muito clara. Poderia nos explicar melhor?

Comment: Esclareça seu problema específico ou acrescente outros detalhes para destacar exatamente o que precisa.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde,

Esta muito vago a sua necessidade, se deseja fazer um update entre um intervalo de datas utlize BETWEEN

```
update suaTabela set seuCampo = seuDado where seuCampo between dataInicial and dataFinal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi, está faltando uma clásula `WHERE` no seu `UPDATE` para você fazer a alteração desejada, como sugestão, utilize um predicado com a data:

```
UPDATE TBL_AULA SET CAMPO_A_ALTERAR = VALOR_ALTERADO WHERE DATA > '2018-01-20';
```

Answer (score 0):

Sobre o UPDATE, as outras respostas são ok e concordo que está um pouco confuso para entender. Mas só para esclarecer mais:

```
UPDATE TBL_AULA SET DATA_AULA = '2018-01-23' WHERE DATA = '2018-01-20';
```

Com isso, todos os registros do dia 20 passarão a ser do dia 23.

Levando em consideração essa pergunta: "ele só vai mexer da data que passei até o fim da tabela. O que preciso e pegar é fazer um update da data que passei e vim subindo?"

Uma vez que você fez esse UPDATE, a ordem dos registros na sua tabela não mudará. Ficará assim:

```
CODIGO_AULA DATA_AULA  TURMA
----------- ---------- ----------
1           2018-01-19 MEC-001
2           2018-01-19 MEC-001
1           2018-01-23 MEC-001
2           2018-01-23 MEC-001
1           2018-01-21 MEC-001
2           2018-01-21 MEC-001
1           2018-01-22 MEC-001
2           2018-01-22 MEC-001
```

Caso você queira que ele seja exibido em ordem, você terá que fazer uma seleção ordenada (SELECT com ORDER BY) levando em consideração o campo DATA_AULA.